# how to link my getEmptyForeignCollection() object with my parent object?

Tags: android, orm, collections, ormlite, foreign-collection

I want to persist an object with two foreignCollections.
But when I try to query the object, my foreignId is always null.
I already read this answers but it doesn't really help me: [Collections in ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524503/collections-in-ormlite)

```
VOPerception perception = new VOPerception();
perception.setOrientation(daoOrientation.createIfNotExists(
    orientationLocalizer.getCurrentOrientation()));
ForeignCollection<VOAccessPoint> fAp =
    daoPerception.getEmptyForeignCollection("accessPoints");
fAp.addAll(wifiLocalizer.getCurrentScanResultMap());    
perception.setAccessPoints(fAp);
daoPerception.create(perception);
List<VOPerception> list = daoPerception.queryForAll();
```

here data are correctly stored but VOAccessPoint objects have no link with the parent VOPerception object.

Here are my two classes:

```
public class VOPerception {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int per_id; 

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager=true)
    ForeignCollection<VOAccessPoint> accessPoints;
    ...
}

public class VOAccessPoint{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
    private int ap_id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign=true,columnName="apForeignPerception_id")
    private VOPerception apForeignPerception;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem @David?  Be sure to accept it and upvote it if so.  That helps my score and yours and makes it more likely that folks will answer your questions in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `queryForAll()` is returning no objects because none of your `VOAccessPoint` instances ever set their `apForeignPerception` field to be `perception`.  Adding the `VOAccessPoint` objects using the `ForeignCollection` added them *to the DAO* but did *not* automagically assign their `apForeignPerception` field.

You should do something like:

```
...
Collection<VOAccessPoint> points = wifiLocalizer.getCurrentScanResultMap();
for (VOAccessPoint point : points) {
    point.setApForeignPerception(perception);
}
fAp.addAll(points);
...
```

I can see how you might think that this would be handled automagically but at the time they are added to the `ForeignCollection`, the `perception` is not even assigned.  I suspect that there is a missing feature for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) here or at least a better exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [`assignEmptyForeignCollection(Obj parent, fieldName)`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#assignEmptyForeignCollection%28T,%20java.lang.String%29). This will create a new foreign collection and all objects you will add via `add(Obj element)` will have the parent value set automatically.