# One-To-Many relationship in ORMLite Android

Tags: java, android, one-to-many, ormlite

How do I implement one-many relationship in ORMLite Android?

please find the example

```
public class A {
 private String name;
    @DatabaseField (foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "A")
    private B b;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "author")
    private String authorName;
}

public class B {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    Collection<A> aees;
}
```

B has collection of A.  I am calling `dao.create(b);`

Now i create dao of b, since b has all the data. But the table B has only created with data, A is never created.  Kindly could some one help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Now i create dao of b, since b has all the data. But the table B has only created with data, A is never created. Kindly could some one help?

Right.  You need to create the `A` items using:

```
for (A a : b.aees) {
   aDao.create(a);
}
```

ORMLite does not automatically create those for you.

You might take a look a the source code of the [foreign-collection example program](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/foreignCollection).

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the DAO of the B class, so when an object B is created or updated, the objects in the collection to be also updated.

Take a look at this question: [Collections in ORMLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524503/collections-in-ormlite).

Answer (score -1):

i was facing the same problem. My json was like:

```
{
   "parent":{
            "name":"ABC",
            "children":[
                          {"childName":"1"},
                          {"childName":"2"},
                          {"childName":"3"}
                       ]
             }
}
```

i resolved the issue like this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setName("ABC");

while(get children one by one from json data)
{
    childrenArray.add(new Child(its Name));
}

parentDAO.create(parent);

for(Child child : childrenArray)
{
    child.setParent(parent);
    childDAO.create(child);
}
```