# How can i do "one-many" relationship?

Tags: java, android, one-to-many, ormlite

I need help with relation "one-many". I would like to use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com) DB for Android.

How can i do this simple example?
[image]

thx

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer: [One-To-Many relationship in ORMLite Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441694/one-many-relationship-in-ormlite-android)

Here are the docs from ormlite.com on [foreign collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection).

Basically you need a trips collection in `Trip_Routes`, something like this.

```
 public class Trip {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "tripName")
    private String tripName;
}

public class Trip_Routes {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "id")
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    private String name;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    Collection<Trip> trips;
}
```

Now you have to create the dao of "Trip_Routes", since "Trip_Routes" has all the data. But the table "Trip_Routes" has only created with data, "Trip" have to be created and you can to use the data from "Trip_Routes" to fill "Trip", something like this.

```
for (Trip t : Trip_Routes.trips) {
   tripDao.create(t);
}
```

Comment: ok When i write this: `@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true )
    private MyTripTable myTripTable;`    that is one - one when is it Collection it is one - many right ?