# updating nested class in ormlite android

Tags: android, ormlite

In ormlite if i say

```
  public class Parent {

   @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoCreate = true, canBeNull = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    Child a = null;
          }
```

Its autocreating and also while retrieving data it gets the child's value also like wise is there anything for update.

```
       example if 
         parent.getChild().setName("aaa");     
         parent.update(p);
```

will it update the child's value too..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524503/collections-in-ormlite

Comment: that i am able to do which i have already mentioned in code but i am asking for an update

Comment: Did you read the duplicated link carefully? first line is `OrmLite does not auto-save nested objects automagically like other ORMs.`