# How to get ForeignCollection Field into Cursor in Ormlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite

I have a `ForeignCollection` field in my table below :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "json_main")
public class JsonMain {

    @DatabaseField( id = true)
    int _id;

    @DatabaseField
    int likes_count;

    @DatabaseField 
    String protected_visibility;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    ForeignCollection<JsonUser>    jsonUser = null;
}
```

And Reference of this table here :

```
@DatabaseTable (tableName = "json_main_user")
public class JsonUser {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int _id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = "parent_id")
    private JsonMain jsonMain;
}
```

I'm Building My Query to get The cursor here :

```
    QueryBuilder<JsonMain, Integer> queryBuilder_main = dao_json_main.queryBuilder();
    PreparedQuery<JsonMain> jsonMains_list =queryBuilder_main.orderBy("sort_id",false).prepare();
    CloseableIterator<JsonMain> closeableIterator = dao_json_main.iterator(jsonMains_list);

    AndroidDatabaseResults androidDatabaseResults=    (AndroidDatabaseResults)closeableIterator.getRawResults();

    Cursor cursor = androidDatabaseResults.getRawCursor();
```

I have inserted the Data Correctly into Database
I want to Know How could I get `ForeignCollection` of json_main table using ormlite using `Cursor` .Above is what I have tried .

Any Answer or Suggestion is Highly Appreciated

Comment: Since I just found your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595251/ormlite-joinning-the-table-not-returning-result), I understand what you want to do. Anyway, I don't think it is possible, since the size of the `ForeignCollection` might vary from result to result of `json_main`. I suppose there is a reason why you have to use a `Cursor` and can't load all in a `List` (?) The only thing I can think of is creating a `Cursor` yourself with `MatrixCursor` out of the `JsonMain` objects. Then you would have to query for the max size of the  `ForeignCollection` first.

Comment: @super-qua Thks that you got my question. I just tried to get ForeignCollection field from the json_main but when I query the json_main I find no method in Cursor to get that field of ForeignCollection

Comment: @super-qua Also the only Possible way is by using the object of JsonMain to get the Collection and iterate to get the result.But again the Problem of Getting Result by into Cursor persit :)#issue

Comment: I think there are two possible solutions: First get the Collection of the `JsonMain` with the `ForeignCollection` filled, and then flatten it by hand to an `Object[]` which you can pass to a `MatrixCursor`. Or second would be to have your `Cursor` as above, then run a second query on the `json_main_user` with a `Cursor` being returned, and combine it with a `CursorJoiner`

Comment: @super-qua Second solution is what I have Tried and Sucessfully...done but without CursorJoiner.Actually I passed the json_main cursor to the Adapter and then in bindView of CursorAdapter I again Queried to get json_main_user.

Comment: @super-qua Also I have not tried how good is this as far as performance is concern.But Sure shortly this could be a Solution.Whats your view over this ? #Suggestion

Comment: I think the performance would be improved if you would create your fully filled cursor first, since now the second query might be run every time your view comes in the viewport. Nevertheless, if it fits your needs and you don't run in performance problems you can definitely stick to your solution. Glad it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have inserted the Data Correctly into Database I want to Know How could I get ForeignCollection of json_main table using ormlite using Cursor .Above is what I have tried .

I hope I understand the question.  The `JsonMain` `Cursor` doesn't have *any* information from the `JsonUser` table.  What it does have is the `_id` field which corresponds to the `jsonMain_id` field which is in the `JsonUser` table.  What you can do is take that `_id` and do a query on the `JsonUser` table to get the associated users.

The only other way to do this would be to construct your own `JOIN` raw query which returns both the main fields and the user fields in one cursor.  Unfortunately [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) won't help much in this scenario.

Comment: Thks for answer.Maybe in future we could get this kind facility in Ormlite .Any Assurance over this ?